# remove tags from a xml file written to a string?

Tags: c#, xml, string

this the what the data in the string looks like:

```
<temp><id>TGPU1</id><label>GPU</label><value>67</value></temp><temp><id>THDD1</id><label>ST3320620AS</label><value>34</value></temp><temp><id>FCPU</id><label>CPU</label><value>1430</value></temp>
```

(there is more, that is just a small snipping of the original output.)
what i would like to do is feed it through some fast code(not in terms of how long the actual code is, but how long it takes to execute) that will remove all the

```
<temp><id>TGPU1</id><label>GPU</label><value>
```

and output it to a new string with only the value between all the `<value>`'s and `</value>`'s. im looking for output in the string like: 67341430.
i found this code:

```
bool FoundMatch = false;

try {
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"<([be])pt[^>]+>.+?</\1pt>");
    while(regex.IsMatch(yourstring) ) {
            yourstring = regex.Replace(yourstring, "");
    }
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

but it only removes the <*pt> which cold be changed to remove something else. but it would only remove one tag at a time. not very fast if i have to remove all tags.

thanks

PS if you wanted to know, the code below is the code i am looking to add this to. this is also the code that printed the original string mentioned above:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Memory mapped file reader started");

    using (var file = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("sensor"))
    {
        using (var reader = file.CreateViewAccessor(0, 3800))
        {
            var encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
            Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(bytes));
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit ...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You should better load your XML into a XElement an manipulate it. It will be much more simpler to do this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
String.Concat(
    XElement.Parse(...)
            .Descendants("value")
            .Select(v => v.Value)
);
```

If you're *really* concerned about performance, you could use `XmlReader` directly to read through `<value>` tags and append to a `StringBuilder`.
However, that's not worth it, unless your XML is hundreds of megabytes large.

Comment: could you explain each line? am i right?: it selects the value between the strings <value></value>? but then what does it do with it? Thanks.

Comment: hey um it compiled fine, but since its more of a string of data rather than a xml file it doesn't have a root. that sample is what the whole thing looks like just repeated with different values.

Comment: Huh? I'm not sure what you're asking.  If you want to parse multiple roots, wrap the string in a dummy tag.

Comment: oh i get a error on the code you provided because their are "multiple root elements" in the sting of data (the output link i just posted) i get the error as an exception once the code is running.